# Using Lagrange multipliers to find two closest points on two lines

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Good day everyone.

I have the following question, which asks to apply Lagrange multipliers technique to solve the optimization problem. So the question is following:

Suppose that L1 is the line of intersection of the planes

\begin{align}
      \ 2x+y+2z=15     \\\\ 
    \ x+2y+3z=30
\end{align}

and that L2 is the line of intersection of the planes

\begin{align}
      \ x-y-2z=15     \\\\ 
    \ 3x-2y-3z=20
\end{align}

Find the closest points P1 and P2 on these two skew lines. (There is a hint as well which says that I should get 10 linear equation to solve).

My attempt to solve it so far was as follows. I decided to derive equations of the lines that result from the intersection of two planes pairs. So, I used two normal vectors of two planes, and by the cross product I got the vector parallel to the intersection line under question. For the L1 line the symmetric equations are these:

\begin{align}
      \ -x=-\frac{\ y-15}{\ 4}=\frac{\ z}{\ 3}
\end{align}

and for the second line, L2
\begin{align}
\ -(x+28)=-\frac{\ y+43}{\ 3}=\ z
\end{align}

Now, I got stuck on this stage. I know that I should use the squared distance formula as an optimization function but how can get to it?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17206/saying-hello-at-the-beginning-of-a-question-answer

Comment: You’ll have an easier time of it if you express the two lines in parametric form. You’ve already done most of the work for that.